# How to update child entity when updating parent in one to many relationship?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I have two entities called A and B. Models are as below.

```
class A {    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "child", cascade={CascadeType.ALL} , orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<B> children = new HashSet<>();
}

class B {
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private A child;
}
```

I want to update class B when I am updating class A. For now lets say, I am having 3 instances of B in A. When updating I want to remove one instance from that.But now, it is not happening. But, if I need to add a new B, to A, it is working. What I am doing wrong? Please let me know.
To update the entity I used the below.

```
public update A(A object){
    A existing = aDao.find(object.getID()) // retrieve the existing object A;
    for(B obj: object.getB()){  // this will create if there are new entities, but, i need to remove alreadet saved B instance if they are not in updated object
        obj.setA(existing);
    }
    existing.setB(object.getB());        
}
```

Comment: do you set child in B to null when you remove B children in A?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I did that also, nothing happened. existing.setB(null)  this will not remove the already saved B entities from the database

Comment: can you post the code where you remove it?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, instead of  existing.setB(object.getB());     I added existing.setB(null) . But it didn't remove the already saved B from db.

Comment: And you also call A.children.remove(B)?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I haven't will do that and let u know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178148/discussion-between-simon-martinelli-and-spc91).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you call remove on the children in A and set the child in B to null:

```
a.getChildren().remove(b);
b.setA(null);
```

A great thing are so called convenience methods that you place on the to one side in your case in A:

```
 public class A {
     // existing code

     // Convenience mehtods
     public void addChild(B b) {
         children.add(b);
         b.setA(this);
     }

     public void removeChild(B b) {
         children.remove(b);
         b.setA(null);
     }
 }
```

That way your bi-directional relationship is always up to date.

Comment: I changed the code, 

  ` for (B object: existingA.getB()){      

       existing.removeChild(object);            
    }
   updatedA =  aDao.update(existing);`
but updatedA still have the data I have saved earlier

Comment: And do you have a transaction?

Comment: what do u mean? I am updating the A object using, aDao.update().

Comment: @Transactional
    public T update(T entity) {
        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(entity);
        return entity;
    }

Comment: Stupid question: You are using Spring Boot. Why don't you use JpaRepository?

Comment: I created a test and everything works as expected. Are you sure that you have the saved instance and not an old A?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178146/discussion-between-spc91-and-simon-martinelli).